# JXCore not running on browser platform

Tags: node.js, cordova, browser, jxcore

I want a JXCore application that can run on android, ios and the browser platforms.

I have used the express sample project provided by JXCore and tested it on my android tablet without any problems. However when I run it on the browser platform, it doesn't seem to work. There are no errors but the output on the web page just says:

```
JXcore plugin: Device type is unkown. Defaulting to Android
```

Are there any additional configuration or plugins required for JXCore to run on the browser platform or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova's "browser" platform just runs local nodejs server which hosts static files. Instead you can run nodejs server as hosted app and reach from browser.

You can see this [jxcore cordova project](https://github.com/karaxuna/jxcore-repl) which works without cordova too, just running `jx www/jxcore/app.js` command.

Comment: @bouncer Yes, you can't use `Mobile` when it's not mobile. You can check `typeof Mobile === 'undefined'` and if Mobile is not available, communicate with websockets for example. Or you can see example project I provided and use websockets only (use `Mobile` just to get server ip address to initialize websocket).

Comment: Sorry I wanted to edit the comment and accidentally deleted it. However I did see that part in your code and that is the correct way to determine if you are running on a mobile device. You can also do the same to test if the application is run by JXCore using: `if (typeof jxcore == 'undefined')`.

Comment: However am I correct when saying that you can either run the app with Cordova or JXCore but you cannot use both when running on a pc/browser platform? Is it possible to still use the cordova.js in your app when run by JXCore?

Comment: @bouncer you don't need cordova.js when running in browser. Yes, you cannot yet run cordova with browser platform and use jxcore inside it.